# Place.formatted_address in google maps api is undefined

Tags: google-maps-autocomplete

I'm trying to get the value of place.formatted_address, but I don't understand why it's undefined everytime I try to console log the value. I'm using this project for the autocomplete function in google maps

```
        const google = window.google;
        const options = {
        componentRestrictions: { country: "mo" },
        fields: ["address_components", "geometry", "icon", "name"],
        strictBounds: false,
        types: ["establishment"],
        };
        const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.$refs["origin"], options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, "place_changed", () => {
            const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place.formatted_address)
            var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
            console.log(lat,lng)
            })
    },
```

Comment: You need to call fetchDetails() to get the value of place.formatted_address if you're using autoComplete.